# Execute Openlayers select interaction after a drawend event with the draw interaction

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

I'm using the latest version of OL and I'm attempting to fire the select interaction independent from the interaction itself. For instance, I allow users to use the draw interaction. However, the select interaction requires another step or event to be fired. I'm looking to perform the select interaction in a drawend event of the draw interaction.

```
    draw.on('drawend', (e) => {
       //Ideally perform select interaction here
    });
```

I'm using react so I am passing in the the `selectClick` interaction into my draw component.

```
const selectEvent = new Select({
    condition: olEvents.click,
});
```

So, my goal is to use it here:

```
    draw.on('drawend', (e) => {
       //Ideally perform select interaction here
        //selectEvent selects the drawn shape
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could push the feature into the select interaction's feature collection as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/box-selection.html

Comment: Pushing the feature into the interaction was correct, but this OL example above adds a ton of cruft. For others that are running into this I would note that all you need to do is get the features from any given source. Then if you access to your select interaction it's as @Mike stated: "You could push the feature into the select interaction's feature collection."